# How to Read a Row into Pandas--that has been broken by a return character

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to read a census [building permits text file](https://www.census.gov/construction/bps/txt/tb3v2016.txt) with several rows that look like the below. 
At times, the description field is too long which causes a line break in the row--which screws up pandas.

```
533 45220 Tallahassee, FL                        1613     810     
999 13980 Blacksburg-Christiansburg-Radford,
  VA                                              543     455
108 11100 Amarillo, TX                            740     718
```

The the below code will read the file into pandas––but many rows are shifted. How do you parse a file text file like this? Many thanks in advance.

```
testdf = pd.read_table('./csv/bldg_permits/metro/tb3u2016.txt', header='infer', 
                       encoding="ISO-8859-1",skiprows=9, 
                       delimiter = '\s+', skipinitialspace=True,
                       error_bad_lines=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas won't be able to patch lines together like that as part of `read_csv()`.
I'd recommend doing a first pass to clean the data (separators are also an issue), and then a second pass to load into Pandas.

First, get data from the URL (I'm using `requests` but any URL parser will do):

```
import pandas as pd
import re
import requests
url = "https://www.census.gov/construction/bps/txt/tb3v2016.txt"
r = requests.get(url)
```

Now iterate over lines, writing each line to `lines`.

```
lines = []
begin_data = 10
backup_by = 1
for i, l in enumerate(r.text.split("\n")[begin_data:]):
    line = (pd.Series(l).str.replace("(,|,\\*) ", "\\1_")
                        .str.replace("([A-z\\.]) ([A-z])", "\\1_\\2", n=-1))
    if line.str.match("\d")[0]: # normal line
        lines.append(line[0])
    elif len(lines) > 0: # not a normal line, add to previous line
        lines[i-backup_by] = lines[i-backup_by].strip() + line[0].strip()
        backup_by += 1

fname = "census_data.txt"
f = open(fname, "w")
_ = [print(line, file=f) for line in lines]
```

Notes on above block:

- Since we're going to read this table into Pandas with a `\s+` delimiter, replace spaces with `_` when they're not part of column delimiters.  We're looking for two of these edge cases in particular:

  - Ex. `Alexandria, LA` --> `Alexandria,_LA`
  - Ex. `Minneapolis-St. Paul-Bloomington` --> `Minneapolis-St._Paul-Bloomington`
- If one line looks funny (meaning it doesn't start with a numeric CSA code), assume that's actually meant to be part of the line before it and add it to that previous line.
- We need to keep track of the index of `lines` that represents the previous line we want to add to.  Each time we iterate over a line of the original data and don't add a new line to `lines`, the difference between our loop counter (`i`) and the index of the last element in `lines` increments by 1.  So we use a counter (`backup_by`) that figures out the correct index of `lines` to append to.

Now read the cleaned text file into Pandas:

```
colnames = ["CSA", "CBSA", "Name", "Total", "1 Unit", "2 Units", 
            "3 and 4 Units", "5 Units or more"]
df = pd.read_table(fname, header=None, names=colnames, encoding="ISO-8859-1", 
                   engine='python', delim_whitespace=True, skipfooter=3)

df.head()
   CSA   CBSA                          Name   Total  1 Unit  2 Units  \
0  999  10180                   Abilene,_TX   55593   55193      400   
1  184  10420                     Akron,_OH  226669  226169        0   
2  999  10500                    Albany,_GA   28679   23686        0   
3  440  10540                    Albany,_OR   98763   97926        0   
4  104  10580  Albany-Schenectady-Troy,*_NY  512058  361454    10605   

   3 and 4 Units  5 Units or more  
0              0                0  
1            500                0  
2            360             4633  
3              0              837  
4          26585           113414
```

At this point, you can go back and remove the `_` placeholders for spaces that were inserted into the `Name` field, if so desired.

Comment: Thank You. Your answer is fantastic! I had to woodshed a little to fully wrap my brain around it--which is a good thing. Much appreciation  for helping me.